# How do I implement setZ() for devices below API 21/Lollipop?

Tags: android

I've succeeded in implementing a drag-slide animation with the `setZ()` function as follows:

```
dragAnimSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        ((ViewGroup)sourceParent.getParent()).setClipChildren(false);
        for(int a = 0; a < ifvList.size(); a++)
        {
            if(a != sourceIndex && a != indexInListener)
            {
                ifvList.get(a).setZ(-20);
            }
        }
        if(sourceParent.indexOfChild(toReplace) != -1 && toReplaceParent.indexOfChild(source) != -1) {
            source.setZ(-10);
        } else {
            sourceParent.setZ(-10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        ((ViewGroup)sourceParent.getParent()).setClipChildren(true);
        for(int a = 0; a < ifvList.size(); a++)
            {
                if(a != sourceIndex && a != indexInListener)
                {
                    ifvList.get(a).setZ(0);
                }
            }
            source.setZ(0);
            sourceParent.setZ(0);
        }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```

However, the app I'm using this in targets devices with a minimum API of 15, and the function `setZ()` only works for API 21 and above.

`bringToFront()` or changing the draw order won't work because it's a LinearLayout and the former will just bring the view to the end of the list.

How can I at least emulate the effect of `setZ()` for devices below API 21?

Answer (score 1):

There is no elevation prior to Lollipop, hence no `setZ()`: the order of drawing is always in order of the views being added.

There is [ViewCompat.setZ()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setZ(android.view.View,%20float)), but obviously it doesn't do anything prior to Lollipop, just allows you to remove any version checks.

Comment: Do I use it like this: `ViewCompat.setZ(<view_to_elevate>, <new_z_value>)` ?

Comment: Yep. Keep in mind that the z value is in pixels, just like `setZ()`

Comment: Does `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ()` do the same thing? Because when I checked out my version's ViewCompat, `setZ()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Just like `view.setZ()` and `view.setTranslationZ()` do different things, so do these. You should really update to the latest support library (24.0.0 as of now).

Comment: Ah. That explains it. My support library is still at 23.2.1. Should I install the ver. 24 build tools too?

Comment: Yes, you'd need the version 24 build tools and the API 24 SDK if you want to use the 24.0.0 Support Library